# centering the a paragraph of text in a paper

Tags: spacing

I need to center the following paragraph inside the paper (at the center of the height of the paper)

> DECLARATION
>
> I hereby declare that the work in this thesis is my own except for quotations and
> summaries, which have been duly acknowledged.

shall I use the
`\vspace*{1\baselineskip}`
moreover, I used the `geometry` package.

Thank you.

Comment: you want to center it vertically ? If so, how about `\vfil` above and below the text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper,showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\null\vfill
\noindent
DECLARATION

\noindent
I hereby declare that the work in this thesis is my own except for quotations and summaries, which have been duly acknowledged.
\vfill
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

The options for `geometry` are just for the example.

Comment: fast answer and very good, it clarifies every thing that I need.
Thank you very much

Comment: Hi @Gonzalo Medina, there is an wanted line in the header. I mean, when I used your code, everything is OK but there is a line in the header below the page numbering. How to remove it? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Montadar as you can see from the image attached,  my code doesn't produce any rules under the header, so there must be some code in your document responsible for the line.  You can try using `\thispagestyle{empty}` right after the first `\clearpage` command (or with `plain` instead of `empty`). If this doesn't solve the problem, compose aa simple, complete document allowing us to reproduce the problem and add it to your question as an edit.

Comment: Ok, I followed your guide. It is working, thank you very much.